# angular x postman x cherrypy - Problem Content-Length on header post

Tags: angular, cherrypy

My application uses Angular (front) and CherryPy (server). When I make a POST call through Postman everything goes well, but when I make the same call through Angular I get an error because on the server I don't receive the "Content-Length" of the header.

Below my debugging code on the server called postman:

[image]

Here is my debugging code on the server called Angular (without "Content-Length"):

[image]

My code Angular:

[image]

How can I solve t? Thanks

Comment: FTR it's best to post actual code, not images. It's hard to read anything on them and impossible to search/compare/copy.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your postman, make the POST request then check the headers:

[image]

Try to reply them on your angular service.

Comment: I reproduced the header generated by the postman but the "Content-Length" still does not appear.
I tried first without the "Content-Length" item to see if it was automatically generated as it happens in postmam, it didn't work. Then it includes this item trying to force it, and even then it does not appear in the server's debug.